# How does parameterization work in Collections.EmptyList class?

Tags: java, generics

I just wonder what happens after I execute:
`List list = Collections.<String>emptyList();`

Here is Collections code:

```
public static final List EMPTY_LIST = new Collections.EmptyList(null);
public static final <T> List<T> emptyList() {
        return EMPTY_LIST;
    }

private static class EmptyList<E> extends AbstractList<E> 
                                  implements RandomAccess, Serializable {

    private EmptyList() {
    }

    //...
}
```

1. How is it possible to call `EmptyList(null)` while `EmptyList` doesn't have constructor with arguments.
2. Please, explain me the process how does `Collection`'s method generic type `T` becomes `EmptyList`'s generic type `E`?

Comment: Where does your code come from? I see different implementations in [jdk 6](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Collections.java) and in [jdk 8](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/jdk/file/3623f1b29b58/src/share/classes/java/util/Collections.java).

Comment: @Rudik, is it OracleJDK? OpenJDK? Or some other JDK? In the JDK implementations I have there's no `(null)` passed to `EmptyList` constructor.

Comment: Verry sorry, this is openJDK 1.7.  powered by Fernflower decompiler.

Comment: So, this is just a decompiler output? Then it's inaccurate. It happens with decompilers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I just wonder what happens after I execute

Nothing *happens* because everything about Generics and type parameters goes on at compile time.

> How is it possible to call `EmptyList(null)` while `EmptyList` doesn't have constructor with arguments

It is not possible, but no JDK code I saw creates the empty list by passing `null` to the constructor. Don't trust decompiler code.

> explain me the process how does `Collection`'s method generic type `T` becomes `EmptyList`'s generic type `E`?

`T` is a type variable capturing the type inferred at each call site of `emptyList()`. This variable is "passed" (during static type analysis) to `emptyList` so that the type of the returned value is `List<T>`. `E` is the name of the type parameter of `EmptyList` and this type parameter assumes the value of `T` in that particular type instantiation. This is very similar to how an `ArrayList<E>`'s `E` becomes `String` when you say `new ArrayList<String>()`.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to @MarkoTopolnik answer I can explain why decompiler shows that `null` is passed into constructor parameters.

When you create private class with no explicit constructor, its default no-arg constructor is generated inside the bytecode as private:

```
private static class EmptyList<E> {
    private EmptyList() {
    }
    ...
}
```

This way the class cannot be instantiated from other classes (JVM will not permit this). But it does instantiated in `Collections` class:

```
public static final List EMPTY_LIST = new EmptyList<>();
```

From the JVM point of view there's no thing like "nested class". The `EmptyList` class is just another class (named `Collections$EmptyList`) in the same package. If javac compiler generate the direct call to the private constructor, then JVM will just throw an exception during the `Collections` class initialization. To fix this problem javac compiler introduces one more additional constructor with package-private access:

```
private static class EmptyList<E> {
    private EmptyList() {
    }

    EmptyList(Collections$1 ignore) {
        this();
    }
    ...
}
```

This artificial constructor has one parameter just to distinguish from the existing constructor. Also to avoid possible arguments clash an additional artificial class `Collections$1` is generated! The purpose of this class is just to be the parameter of such artificial constructors. It's never instantiated and even initialized.

So finally you can instantiate the `EmptyList` from another class (within `java.util` package) calling this new constructor:

```
public static final List EMPTY_LIST = new EmptyList<>((Collections$1)null);
```

This is how it looks in the bytecode. Seems that decompiler is not smart enough to detect this situation and remove the artificial constructor parameter in the output (actually it should be quite simple).

Comment: To what lengths Java had to go just to preserve backward compatibility with the crappy 1.0 :(

Answer (score 1):

Your decompiled code:

```
public static final List EMPTY_LIST = new Collections.EmptyList(null);
```

Actual code

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static final List EMPTY_LIST = new EmptyList<>();
```

In the actual code, there is no parameter to the constructor.

Your decompiled code:

```
public static final <T> List<T> emptyList() {
    return EMPTY_LIST;
}
```

Actual code:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static final <T> List<T> emptyList() {
    return (List<T>) EMPTY_LIST;
}
```

So, as for how does the type `T` becomes `E`? By cheating. `EMPTY_LIST` is a *raw type*, and they explicitly cast it into `List<T>` and suppress the warnings both on creation of the original `EMPTY_LIST` and on this explicit cast.

In reality, this is pretty safe exactly because the list is empty and will stay empty.

Moral of the story: don't trust decompilers, especially not when it comes to generics, because with type erasure, it's really hard for a decompiler to know what actually happened in the original source code. If you want to look at the source of various open-source Java projects, including OpenJDK, use the useful (though slow) [GrepCode website](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7u40-b43/java/util/Collections.java).